# Kill SQL query execution if it exceeds allotted time in DB2

Tags: c#, .net, db2, db2-luw

I'm creating a program in .NET that uses the IBM DB2 .NET provider(IBM.Data.DB2) to connect to a DB2 database(v9.7) and run select queries.

The program should terminate the SQL execution, if a submitted select query takes more than 5 seconds to return the data.

To implement this as per [IBM's documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClassConnectionStringProperty.html) I could use the QueryTimeout parameter in the connection.

```
string connStr = "Server=server:12345;Database=db;UID=user;PWD=pass; QueryTimeout = 5;";

            DB2Connection conn = null;
            DB2Command cmd = null;

            conn = new DB2Connection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("IBM DB2: " + conn.IsOpen);
            if (conn.IsOpen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionTimeout);
                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from user.orders";                    
                DB2DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int counter = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    counter += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetDB2Int64(0));
                }                    
                reader.Close();                    
            }
            conn.Close();
```

When I ran the query in winSQL, the query took about 20 seconds to execute. But when I execute it in this program, it took me the same 20 seconds. As per the documentation the query should have terminated in 5 seconds.

Why has the execution not stopped?

PS: I've also tried setting the ***cmd.CommandTimeout to 5*** and it still would not stop the execution.

Comment: What happens if you set the _cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;_ ?

Comment: @Steve, it still runs for 20 seconds.

Comment: How do you measure your 20 seconds? In your case, since you are fetching from a cursor, I presume each CLI call is subject to a separate timeout, so `ExecuteReader` (probably just opens a cursor) or any `Read` (likely a fetch from the cursor) duration must exceed 5 seconds for the timeout to kick in.

Comment: Besides, setting `QueryTimeout` is not _guaranteed_ to "kill" the query; the driver will send an interrupt request to the server, but the server might have its own ideas about what to do with it. You could enable client tracing to see if and when the interrupt request is sent.

Comment: @mustaccio, I think I understand the fact that a cursor is opened, and that is why the it does not stop. Using a data adapter to fill a dataset should execute the SQL at one shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above example is that ExecuteReader() creates a cursor to the database that pulls the data as an when its read, so the query never times out.

But using a DataAdapter to a dataset, pulls the data in a single go. So the below seems to kill the execution.

```
string connStr = "Server=server:12345;Database=db;UID=user;PWD=pass;";
conn = new DB2Connection(connStr);
conn.Open();

if (conn.IsOpen)
{
    Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionTimeout);
    cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from orders";
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;

    DB2DataAdapter adp = new DB2DataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows){
        Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: As per documentation, `DB2DataAdapter` does not automatically generate the SQL statements required to reconcile changes made to a DataSet associated with the database.

Comment: @fabfas I'm not sure I get your point. My restriction was that I create a system that did not let an SQL, that took more than 5 seconds to return data, to run. I was using the querytimeout and commandTimeout, which did not yield what I was looking for because I was using a reader to pull the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Read [`DB2Command.CommandTimeout`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2CommandClassCommandTimeoutProperty.html) property tutorial on IBM website. I hope this will solve your problem. C# example code is below:

**[C#]**

```
public void CreateMyDB2Command()
{
  string mySelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY EMPNO";
  DB2Command myCommand = new DB2Command(mySelectQuery);
  myCommand.CommandTimeout = 20;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, but the problem was I was doing an execute reader, that was opening a cursor. So every call made to the cursor was connecting to the DB and pulling small pieces of data that never times out.